# .net MVC Odata endpoint works on POST, but 404s on GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api

My question should have a simple answer, but after hours of experimentation and googling, I have nothing so now I'm here.

I am working with .net MVC 5 odata 2.0.  I am trying to create a new odata endpoint that works on a get.  I've successfully created a few endpoints that work with POST, but I can't seem to get one that works as a GET.

relevant code

WebApiConfig.cs

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Review>("Reviews");
builder.EntitySet<Strategy>("Strategies");
ActionConfiguration ReviewsInStrategy = builder.Entity<Strategy>().Action("ReviewsInStrategy");
ReviewsInStrategy.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Review>("Reviews");
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

StrategiesController.cs

```
[EnableQuery]
 public IQueryable<Review> ReviewsInStrategy([FromODataUri] Guid key){
    Strategy strategy = db.Strategies.Find(key);
    return strategy.Reviews
 }
```

Now I go to fiddler and try a GET to

[myurl]/odata/Strategies(guid'[myguid]')/ReviewsInStrategy

I get a 404 result.  But when I change fiddler to a POST (no other change - I don't add accept headers or content types or anything) it works just fine.

How do I make this work with GET?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Get-function to your controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Strategies> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
{
    IQueryable<Strategies> result = db.Strategies.Where(p => p.Id == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

That way you can use a GET request on the Strategies-resource. If you still want to use a custom action you must add the parameter to your config:

```
ActionConfiguration ReviewsInStrategy = builder.Entity<Strategy>().Action("ReviewsInStrategy").Returns<Review>().Parameter<Guid>("Key");

[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("ReviewsInStrategy(Key={key})")]
public IHttpActionResult<Review> ReviewsInStrategy([FromODataUri] Guid key){
    Strategy strategy = db.Strategies.Find(key);
    return Ok(strategy.Reviews);
 }
```

Not sure if all this works with the complex type `Guid`. Maybe you need to change it to string and parse it inside the function. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) is a good msdn article about this.